# PayPal Donate button - Issues

Tags: paypal, donation

I'm trying to implement and test the [Donate Button](https://paypal.com/donate/button) by PayPal, and I've faced the issues with it.

I'm having a Personal account as a person, not as a non-profit organization. Everything seems like working fine, but on the final step, I'm getting a message on the interface:

```
Sorry, we weren't able to complete your payment at this time. Please try again later.
If you continue to encounter problems, please contact customer service.
```

I've contacted the PayPal support, but the last time when I did, I've waited for a few days for a not complete response.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That link is borked, it just takes me to the home page.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I've updated the link. It appears that when adding `www.` to the URL, it's not pointing to the same address.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect that to work.  "Donate" isn't just a cutesy word used by cam girls. "Donate" has a specific meaning in nonprofits: specifically it means the organization has US 501(c) tax status (or certain recognized foreign equivalents), *and because of that*, donors are entitled to a tax deduction on their IRS Form 1040 Schedule A.

It is vital to distinguish the two - so people making a donation don't have misplaced expectations regarding the tax status of their donations, and so they don't accidentally take a tax deduction they're not entitled to.  Thus, PayPal has good reason to keep their "donate" button reserved for actual nonprofits.

PayPal has a significant presence in the nonprofit space.  We use Donate buttons on our site, but we had to go through a fair amount of "rigmarole" to prove that yes, in fact, we are a genuine 501(c) nonprofit.

Note that this is a "peculiarity" of US nonprofit tax treatment. For instance I donate $60 and the government kicks me back $20 on my taxes. Whereas in the UK, I donate $40 and the gov't matches $20 (for bona-fide nonprofits). So it matters less.

Comment: I don't think PayPal requires you to be a non-profit to receive donations: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/fundraising#Makegivingeasier then click on "Learn about creating a donation button" and the popup says: "Please note: Fundraisers that are not verified nonprofits will be asked to demonstrate how their donations will be used, once they raise more than $10,000."